# How to open page at a certain position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I set and get the current web page scroll position?

I have a chat with position fixed and if you decide to close it, the page reloads and goes back to top, which is annoying for users..because they have to scroll back down to the point they were at.

If I could save the current scroll position (in a hidden input) before the page reloads, I could then set it back after it reloads.. right? But please, show me how to do it because I am new to this.

```
function closeChat() {
    var x = document.getElementById("chatArea");

    if(x.style.display == 'block'){
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    window.location.assign("explore.php");
    return false;
}
```

PS: I have to assign to the same page because I am sending a parameter through the url and when the chat is closed, the parameter is still there... so that's why

Comment: You could either add a hash to the url or set a value in local storage. You can access the scroll position with `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can save the position of the scroll in your closeChat function and store it in your localstorage

```
function closeChat() {
    var x = document.getElementById("chatArea");

    if(x.style.display == 'block'){
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    localStorage.setItem('scrollValue', window.scrollY) // set it here
    window.location.assign("explore.php");
    return false;
}
```

Then on page load, you just add that value to window.scrollTo(x, y)

```
const scrollValue = localStorage.getItem("scrollValue")
window.scrollTo(0, scrollValue ? scrollValue : 0)
```

Comment: yeees, it works!! Thank you very much!! But any idea how to hide the scroll? I mean, it's a bit frustrating to see how the page starts from top and goes to the certain point...

Comment: Same problem here:
I want to directly open a html page on a specific position without scrolling. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can save the current scroll in local storage and restore it when the page reloads

```
// when leaving the page
window.localStorage.setItem('scroll', x.scrollTop);


// when entering the page
x.scrollTop = localStorage.getItem('scroll');
```

hope it helped :)

Comment: And what is x? Because in my code, x is just a div

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't work.. maybe because the chatArea has position fixed..

Comment: I don't think the position fixed is related to the scroll that way. x is the chat you want to scroll in like in your example. when I tested it and assigned a value for `scrollTop` of a position fixed div it worked ok. I am sorry but I don't know what is the problem now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to get the scrollTop property of the element under the chat box. Then you store it in the local storage and access it upon closing the the chatbox.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).